# Erro when open excel in background

Tags: excel, vba, background

My english is bad, sorry!

My code:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Set AppExcel = New Excel.Application
AppExcel.ScreenUpdating = False
AppExcel.Workbooks.Open "Q:\Registro de Desenhos.xls", ReadOnly:=True

End Sub
```

In my PC I do loggin with my user and run code without error. Recently I created a New user. When I do loggin with new user the code break when try open workbook in background, but if I set visible = true before opening workbook... Open without error. And if I do loggin old user is all normal.

The error menssage is:

"System error &h800706BE (-2147023170). Remote procedure call failed."

How fix it?

Tks!

Comment: `ScrennUpdating` should be `ScreenUpdating`, but guessing that's just in copying to the question.  Is this code running from within Excel?  You don't mention any other application in your tags and you don't need to reference the application if the code is in the application.

Comment: Hi!

This Scrennupdating error was only here on the site, in the program it is correct.

Yes, the code is running in Office 365 Excel VBA.

Comment: Could you post enough code so that we can reproduce the error?  i.e. A full procedure with `Sub....End Sub` that causes the problem.  [mcve]

Comment: yea! I will edit the original post.